# When used Sub and Aud Claim of payload on a system with JSON Web Token

Tags: authentication, jwt

I'm conducting tests to understand and implement a system of user authorization through the use of JSON Web Token.

Looking for information about the configuration of a token arises me a couple of questions about the use of two Claim Payload, the Sub and Aud.

```
{
    "iss": "www.miweb.com", // issuer
    "iat": 1455550200, // time was issued
    "exp": 1455559810, // expiration timestamp
    "nbf": 1455550260, // not before
    "jti": "31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0", // unique identifier

    "sub": "", // ¿subject?
    "aud": "", // ¿?

    "data": {/* attached data */}
}
```

From what I've observed is rarely used these two claim. My question then is:

**What scenario can give use and for what purpose?**

Thank you very much, greetings

Same written in Spanish StackOverflow question: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/11786/5984

Ps: Sorry for the language, not domain.

*Edited: Translation of comments in the code*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Subject](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) (`'sub'`) claim identifies the user or application (in case of [client credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)) that was authenticated.
The [Audience](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) (`'aud'`) claim indicates who the token is issued for.

Suppose my client application needs to call `service A` of behalf of `user X`.

Typically, my application would communicate with the authorization server to authenticate the user (for example using one of the [OAuth2 grant flows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2)) and request access to `service X`. The authorization server would authenticate the user and ask for consent.

If the user gives consent, the authorization server will issue a JWT token with a subject claim unique for `user X` and an audience claim indicating `service A`.

Comment: Hello MvdD. Perfectly clear, thank you very much. Regards,

Comment: In this scenario what claim would represent the client application?

Comment: @Cirem in case of the client credentials flow, the `sub` claim represents the client.